# How to Passwords cannot contain sequences of 3 or more of the same character?

Tags: php

This is the right method....

```
if(strtolower($pass) == '/\d{3}/')

  {
  form_error($form, t('Passwords cannot contain sequences of 3 or more of the same character.'));
  }
```

Plz some one help me...

Comment: You mean three consecutive ones as a substring or overall in the whole string as a subsequence?

Comment: No it's not the right method.

Answer (score 4):

```
if(preg_match('/(.)\1\1/', $pass))
```

Comment: Does this work? The following gives me 00 instead of 01: 

    echo preg_match('/(.)\1\1/', "test");
    echo preg_match('/(.)\1\1/', "teeest");

Comment: @cherouvim, it gives 01 as expected for me.  I copied your exact examples.  I'm testing with PHP 5.3.3.

Comment: OK thanks. I tested with http://writecodeonline.com/php/ which may have an older PHP version or a different regex implementation (is that possible?).

Comment: @cherouvim: Perhaps, but PCRE has had support for backreferences in patterns since antiquity so I wouldn't be too sure.

Comment: @cherouvim, it's running PHP 4.4.9 (`echo phpversion();`).  That was released in August 2008!  Needless to say, it is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use regular expressions, you will need to call [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) or a similar function.

The regular expression you are looking for is:

```
(.)\1\1
```

That means "any character" followed by the same character followed by the same character.  "\d" is to match a single digit character.  The "same character" part is due to the use of a backreference - ie, the exact same match that was achieved by the first captured (ie, in brackets) pattern in the regular expression.

Here is some code with tests to allow you to play around:

```
function three_in_a_row($string_to_test) {
    return preg_match('/(.)\1\1/', $string_to_test);
}

$test_strings = array(
    array('abcdefg'. false),
    array('aaa', true),
    array('baaa', true),
    array('aaab', true),
);

foreach ($test_strings as $test_string_item) {
    list($test_string, $expected_result) = $test_string_item;
    $actual_result = three_in_a_row($test_string);
    if ($actual_result != $expected_result) {
        printf("Testing string '%s'.  Expected %d, got %d.\n", $test_string, $expected_result, $actual_result);
    }
}
```